# Too many tcp connections in CLOSE_WAIT state on Netty based http server

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, netty

I am working on a Netty based http web server, which is handling heavy concurrent traffic. This http serve is behind ELB. Because of too many concurrent connections we have increased max file descriptor limit from 200000 to 400000.But we are now facing too many tcp connections in CLOSE_WAIT state and still application goes down with too many open files error. we are quite sure that none of the server is handling 400000 request at a time, then what is the reason for too many open files and too many tcp connections in CLOSE_WAIT ?

If we go back to old max file limit 200000, we only encounter too many open files error and very small amount of tcp connections in CLOSE_WAIT which i am not able to understand.

Can anyone explain the reason for this behaviour ?